# How to use on conflict on constraint in postgres with update query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update "name" column in my database, that has more than 300000 records. The name field has a unique constraint on it

While bulk updating I want to skip the records that are violating the constraint

```
update "profiles" set name = left(name, -1) 
where ---------
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT profiles_name_key 
DO NOTHING
```

The above query is throwing an error on "ON"

**edit**

It is not necessary to use ON CONFLICT. Any query that can update the records that doesn't conflict with constraint will work

Comment: There is no `UPDATE ... ON CONFLICT`. If you're looking to do an "upsert", you'll need `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. Take a look at the `UPDATE` grammar here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Comment: Or perhaps you need `MERGE`, new in PostgreSQL v15.

Comment: I don't need an upsert. I only want to update if there are no conflicts. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get what you are looking for with  `update ... on conflict` - that structure **does not exist**. But you can get it with a transaction block. While you will get an exception you can *intercept it* and continue processing. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OcWZprqx))

```
do $$
begin 
    begin -- nested block 
        update <table> 
           set <column> = '<existing value'
         where <column> = '<other existing value>';
    exception 
        when others then null;
    end;  -- nested block
    
    -- other code here will still execute

end ; 
$$;
```